# Order a list, commands not working

Tags: r

I have the following list:

mylist

```
[[1]]
[1] 11
[[2]]
[1] 9
[[3]]
[1]
10
```

I would like to sort it.
I have tried

```
sort(mylist)
```

> Error: mylist must be atomic

```
sort.list(mylist)
```

> Error in sort.list(mylist) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
>   Have you called 'sort' on a list?

```
order(mylist)
```

> Error in order(mylist) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to `order` on a `vector`.  Here, assuming that the `list` have only length of 1 for each element, `unlist` the 'mylist', `order` on the `vector` and then use that

```
mylist[order(unlist(mylist))]
#[[1]]
#[1] 9

#[[2]]
#[1] 10

#[[3]]
#[1] 11
```

Comment: Solved the problem using lists. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `purrr` package is probably overkill for this task, but it is worth exploring if you're looking for a toolkit for working with lists:

```
library(purrr)
mylist %>% sort_by(sort)
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll check it in the future

Answer (score 1):

Your list only contains one value per entry. So you can also convert it to a vector first by using `do.call(c,...)` and then sort the vector:

`sort(do.call(c,mylist))`

```
#[1]  3 10 20
```

Comment: Yes, I knew this solution but I was trying to check if there was a way for a list (just for curiosity). I haver voted up because someone who does not know might find it useful